# Find width of pdf form field in python

Tags: python, pdf

I have a fillable pdf with fields that need to be filled out by the user. I am trying to auto-generate responses to for those fields with python, but I need to know the width/length of the form fields in order to know whether my responses will fit in the field.

How do I find the width of these fields, or at least test whether a possible response will fit?

I was thinking that if I knew the font and font size of the field, that might help.

Edit: I just realized that the pdf is encrypted, so interfacing with the pdf in a programmatic way may be impossible. Any suggestions for a quick and dirty solution are welcome though.

Link to form: http://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a1/form/af910/af910.pdf

I need to know the width of the comments blocks.

Comment: Could you show what the form looks like? Also are you using PyPDF?

Comment: How many fields need to be filled by the user?

Comment: There are 4 fields that need to be filled, but they are all the same width, so I just need the length on one. I have not used PyPDF, but I don't need the script to directly input to the PDF. I just need a string that will copy and paste and fit in the field.

Comment: @SlicedBadge So you have a pdf file, and you want to figure out the max length of a string that will fit into the pdf file's form fields using only Python?

Comment: @GBlomqvist yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

After some quick digging around in pdf files and [one of Adobe's pdf references](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) ([source](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)) it turns out that a text field may have a key "MaxLen" whose value is an integer representing the maximum length of the field's text, in characters (See page 444 in the reference mentioned). It appears that if no such key is present, there is no maximum length.

What one could do then, is simply search the pdf file for the "MaxLen" keys (if multiple text fields, else you could just search for one) and return their values. E.g.:

```
import re

with open('your_file.pdf', 'r', errors='ignore') as pdf_file:
    content = pdf_file.read()

    # Matches every substring "n" (n is an integer) with a preceding "/MaxLen "
    regexp = '(?<=\/MaxLen )\d+'
    max_lengths = [int(match) for match in re.findall(regexp, content)]
```

(If the file is huge you may not be able to read it all into memory at once. If that's the case, reading it line by line could be a solution.)

max_lengths will then be a list of all the "MaxLen" values, ordered after occurrence in the file (the first occurrence will be first etc.).

However, depending on what you need, you may need to further your search and add more conditionals to my code. For example, if a file contains multiple text fields but not all of them has a maximum length, you may not know which length correspond to which field. Also, if a pdf file has been modified and saved (not using "Save As"), the modifications will be appended to the old file instead of overwriting it completely. I'm not sure exactly how this works, but I suppose it could make you get the max lengths of previously removed fields etc. if you're not careful and check for that.

(Working with pdf's in this way is very new to me, please correct me if I'm wrong about anything. I'm not saying that there's no library that can do this for you, maybe PDFMiner can, though it will probably be more advanced.)

---

**Update 23-10-2017**

I'm afraid the problem just got a lot harder. I believe you still should be able to deduce the widths of the text fields by parsing the right parts of the pdf file. Why? Because Adobe's software can render it properly (at least Adobe Acrobat Pro DC) without requiring some password to decrypt it first. The problem is that I don't know *how* to parse it. Dig deep enough and you may find out, or not.

I suppose you could solve the problem in a graphical way, opening every pdf with some viewer which can read them properly, then measuring the widths of the text fields. But, this would be fairly slow and I'm not sure how you would go about recognizing text fields.

It doesn't help that the forms don't use a monospaced font, but that's a smaller problem that definitely can be solved (find which font the text fields use, look up the width of all the characters in that font and use that information in your calculations).

If you do manage to solve the problem, please share. :)

Comment: The field limit is not in characters. After looking at pg 444 of that ref you linked, I believe the DoNotScroll flag is enabled. This limits the size of the field in space but not in characters, so WWW takes up more room than iii.

Comment: @SlicedBadge Interesting, could you upload one of those PDFs somewhere and share a download link?

Comment: It's a common form from the air force. I added a link in the question description.

Comment: @SlicedBadge I've not managed to solve the problem, see the updated answer.